# I got an error when i run the project another system... how can i solve it?

Tags: php, laravel

> Declaration of PDO::query(string $query, ?int $fetchMode = null, mixed ...$fetchModeArgs) must be compatible with Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection::query()

Comment: What is the PHP version on both system?

Comment: PHP 8.0.2 (cli) (built: Feb  3 2021 18:36:40) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64 )

Comment: What is laravel version . Also share version for "doctrine/dbal"  from composer.lock

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 8 on the system where you are getting the error, it can be the incompatible doctrine/dbal. It is the bug and you can find more detail here.

https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3791

I face similar issue and had switched to PHP 7.4 .

But all this only if your system has php 8